# Collapse successor of singular while preseving supercompactness

Tags: set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

Suppose $\kappa$ is a supercompact cardinal. Is it possible to find a forcing which collapses $\kappa^{+\omega+1}$ to $\kappa^{+\omega}$ (all those $\kappa^{+n}$'s are preserved) while the supercompactness of $\kappa$ is preserved?

Comment: Suppose that there is a Woodin cardinal above $\kappa$, can you do some tricks to ensure that the stationary tower will preserve the supercompactness?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I doubt it. Isn't it the case that such a forcing, let's say $P_\lambda$ always singularize some inaccessible $\theta$ which lives in between $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ to be of confinality $\omega$?

Comment: You can use the proper class version of the stationary tower. Do you want a set-sized forcing?

Comment: @MonroeEskew, will it make a big difference? If there are proper class of Woodin cardinal isn't it true by density argument that the class forcing factorize at some initial segment $P_{\lambda}$ for some Woodin cardinal $\lambda$?

Comment: @JiachenYuan Yes that should be true.  But it’s possible that you need to add the full proper-class sized generic to restore supercompactness.

Comment: The point is that $\kappa$ is supercompact in the generic ultrapower by elementarity, but  with the proper-class tower, the ultrapower *is* the generic extension.

Comment: @Monroe: Do you have a good reference for that?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Paul Larson’s book.